# Change fields in node from code

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How do I access the fields in a node in Drupal 7.
I have tried this but that do not work.

```
 $node=node_load($nid);
 $node->field_num[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']=$num;
```

I think I have to be more specific:
I first create a node and set values on some fields like this:

```
 $values = array(
'type' => 'scorings',
'uid' => $user->uid,
'status' => 1,
'comment' => 0,
'promote' => 0,
);
 $entity = entity_create('node', $values);
 $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
 $entity->field_rond_nid[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']=$nid_scorekort;
 $entity->field_golfid[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']=$form_state['values']['golfid_1'];
 $ewrapper->save(true);
 entity_save('node', $entity);
 $nid=$entity->nid;
```

This works fine. Then I want to access this node from another function (passing the nid to it) end set value to another field (field_score_1). I have tried this:

```
 $node=node_load($nid, 'my_content type');
 $node->field_score_1[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['value'] = $my_value;
```

But this do not work. Seams that node_load do not give me access to the fields.

Comment: just `dpm($node)` and see yourself. Install Devel module for `dpm()`

Comment: To make the question more clear I have edit it.

Comment: Your first snippet seems to be correct, and the snippet at the end of the question is wrong. See the node_load() in api.drupal.org. your second argument to node_load should be a revision ID or don't pass any value.

Comment: Thanks, That and load_save($nod) fix it for me.

Comment: Stuck again!
This works fine when just set values to the node. But fore one field attach to the node I need to icnreese the current value with 1. Therefore I need to read the current value. How do I get that field value?

Comment: Well, after some struggling I got it. When reading the fields I have to put in an index 0 in the array, like this: 
    field_score[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']
I can not say that it is easy to find documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `node_load()` call is incorrect.

From the Drupal API documentation for [`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) the function declaration is:

```
node.module node_load($nid = NULL, $vid = NULL, $reset = FALSE)
```

Your second parameter is a string, not a number, as $vid would be.

If `node_load()` returns a `FALSE` then it failed.

Perhaps you were wanting to use [`EntityFieldQuery()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) instead?

Comment: I just put the second parameter away like this and i t seams to work:
 $node=node_load($nid)